# Search and replace part of string in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to replace all iframe tags, stored as nvarchar in my database. I can find the entries using the following sql-question:

```
SELECT * FROM databasename..VersionedFields WHERE Value LIKE '%<iframe%'
```

Say I want to replace the following code segment:

```
code before iframe <iframe src="yadayada"> </iframe> code after iframe
```

With this:

```
code before iframe <a>iframe src="yadayada"</a> code after iframe
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I think 2 update calls should do

```
update VersionedFields
set Value = replace(value,'<iframe','<a><iframe')

update VersionedFields
set Value = replace(value,'> </iframe>','</a>')
```

Answer (score 100):

You can do it with an UPDATE statement setting the value with a REPLACE

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Column = Replace(Column, 'find value', 'replacement value')
WHERE
    xxx
```

You will want to be extremely careful when doing this! I highly recommend doing a backup first.

Comment: [Here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-mysql-database-using-sql/) there are more info about it

Answer (score 13):

```
update VersionedFields
set Value = replace(replace(value,'<iframe','<a>iframe'), '> </iframe>','</a>')
```

and you do it in a single pass.

Answer (score 4):

I was just faced with a similar problem. I exported the contents of the db into one sql file and used TextEdit to find and replace everything I needed. Simplicity ftw!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing a CLR replace function with RegEx support for this kind of string manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

Update database and 
Set fieldName=Replace (fieldName,'FindString','ReplaceString')