# T-SQL string replace in Update

Tags: string, t-sql, replace

I need to update the values of a column, with a substring replace being done on the existing values.

Example:

Data contains `abc@domain1`, `pqr@domain2` etc.

I need to update the values such that `@domain2` is replaced with `@domain1`.

Comment: How many email address does each column have?  Are abc@domain1 and pqr@domain2 in the same column?

Comment: yeah - they are in the same column..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search and replace part of string in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605768/search-and-replace-part-of-string-in-database)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The syntax for [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

REPLACE (string_expression,string_pattern,string_replacement)

So that the SQL you need should be:

```
UPDATE [DataTable] SET [ColumnValue] = REPLACE([ColumnValue], 'domain2', 'domain1')
```

Comment: In my case I needed to replace a double quote with a single quote. I used the following REPLACE([ColumnValue], '"', ''''). The end is four single quotes.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone cares, for `NTEXT`, use the following format:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST([ColumnValue] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'find','replace') AS NTEXT) 
    FROM [DataTable]
```

Comment: That statement in itself doesn't execute the update.

you need to do the following:

UPDATE [DataTable] SET
SET [ColumnValue] = CAST(REPLACE(CAST([ColumnValue] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'domain2','domain1') AS NTEXT) 
    FROM [DataTable]

Answer (score 6):

```
update YourTable
    set YourColumn = replace(YourColumn, '@domain2', '@domain1')
    where charindex('@domain2', YourColumn) <> 0
```

Comment: Does including the where clause as in this answer provide any efficiency gains over the accepted answer?