# Which charset is '&amp;lt;'?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I found this character in my phpbb database: `&amp;lt;`. Which charset is?

I'm on MySQL, and I have PhpBB and phpmyadmin. The code shows `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are HTML Special Characters. You can get full list of them [here](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm). It doesn't have much to do with charset.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. Secondly, can you tell me why it shows up correctly in phpbb forum, and it doesn't show correctly in vbulletin? I mean, in phpbb i have '<', in vbulletin I have '&lt;'. :/

Comment: I'm not sure but in vBulletin it might be escaped to show up correctly in the post.

Answer (score 8):

That's not a charset, it is a *character entity reference*.

That's an *escaping* method known in HTML and XML (where ampersands may have special meaning).

The charset and encoding could still be anything (such as ASCII7, UTF8 or latin1, or basically anything else, since `&amps;` can be expressed in any modern character set).

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. Secondly, can you tell me why it shows up correctly in phpbb forum, and it doesn't show correctly in vbulletin? I mean, in phpbb i have '<', in vbulletin I have '&lt;'. :/

Comment: @DanieleImpagliazzo Most likely PhpBB pre-parses the entity (`&amp;lt;` --> `&lt;` --> `<`) but vbulletin passes it to the page as is so the browser interprets it as `&amp;lt;` --> `&lt;`.

Comment: @DanieleImpagliazzo It would be showed "correctly" (well, incorrectly) if it was being treated as HTML and, hence, not further escaped. However, if the value is treated as plain text, then any HTML special characters (like `&`) would be escaped _again_ resulting in `&amp;`. What is _correct_ depends exclusively on the application. And it needs to be _symmetric_. Usually an error like this means input is not being sanitized of escaped before being "treated as HTML"

Comment: Is there any way to converte these entities from the database?

Comment: @DanieleImpagliazzo of course. `UPDATE your_table SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '&amp;', '&') WHERE your_field LIKE '%&amp;%'`. Etc. Whether or not this is a good idea _depends on the application_, again.

Comment: @DanieleImpagliazzo: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14282302).