# Write a string to XSLT using c# with retaining the xml tags

Tags: c#, xslt

I have an XSLT file in which I need to dynamically add some tags based on a condition. I am using c# StreamWriter to write a string to the XSLT file.
Consider the following string to be written in XSLT file

```
 string appender = "<!--" + " ifdef ${_xml_preprocess}  -->" +
                  " < !--< xsl:variable name = " + 
                  "\"${COLUMN}\"" + " >" +
                  "</ xsl:variable > -->" +
                  "< !--endif-- >";
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("//myPathToXSLTFile");
 writer.write(appender);
```

But when the above string is written in XSLT,

```
    '<' element is replaced as '&amp;lt;'
    '>' element is replaced as '&amp;gt;'
    '\"' element is replaced as '&amp;quot;'
```

But I want the string to be written to XSLT file exactly without any such Replacements. Help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could not reproduce with your code. Content is exactly what you expect.

Comment: Is there any other way to write a string to XSLT as such without any replacements?

Comment: It writes me with `StreamWriter`. You could try `File.WriteAllText`, but it still [uses StreamWriter internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,3768ad284a63029f)

Comment: Thanks @Reniuz Instead I want to write this string to inner text of a node. How could that be possible?

Comment: Ahh it's totally different things. You can't write xml as inner text without encoding elements. If you write for example this without encoding: `<root><item></item></root>`. `item` in this case is inner text here or actual xml element? It is normal to encode and don't see any issues here - when you read you will get elements replaced back.

Comment: How am I supposed to do the encoding of elements?

Comment: They are already encoded - you wrote that `<` is replaced with `&amp;lt;` Check  this: [What is &amp;lt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638095/which-charset-is-amplt)

Comment: Using XSLT code to modify XSLT stylesheets is far simpler.