# Compare French character stored in DB with french string

Tags: php, mysql

I have some french names stored in a Mysql DB like this 'CHEF D’ÉQUIPE DU SERVICE À LA CLIENTÈLE' is stored as `'CHEF D&#8217;&#201;QUIPE DU SERVICE &#192; LA CLIENT&#200;LE'`, htmlentitties of the string. When I do a search directly in DB like this,

```
select * from table where name ='CHEF D&#8217;&#201;QUIPE DU SERVICE &#192; LA CLIENT&#200;LE'
```

its giving results but when I do the same thing in PHP, its not giving any results.

Comment: Why do you have HTML entities in your database to begin with?

Comment: Its not me, it was imported by someone else. Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: You could use the stored function I wrote in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14282302) to unescape the text.

Answer (score 1):

try this query before execute your main query. ("SET NAMES 'UTF-8').

Comment: Is it possible to do this outside of the PDO initialization ( I am not authorized to change the file where it does new PDO())?

Comment: I'm not working with PDO. But in mysqli, if your execute your query after execute SET query, your code should be works.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to edit the PDO DB connect file, now its working.