# MySQL Replace &#39; with '

Tags: php, mysql

I have a wordpress website, and I want to edit all posts content which have one or more occurrence of `&#39;`.  I want only to replace `&#39;` with `'`.

And I want to do that from phpMyAdmin with SQL command.  Please tell me how to do that correctly, I do not want to mess the whole database.

Comment: `UPDATE my_table SET my_column = REPLACE(my_column, '&#39;', '\'')`?

Comment: something like that, it will replace correctly ?

Comment: @eggyal That would have been a fine answer.

Comment: it must replace all occurrence from post content , not my column

Comment: make your comment as answer and i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want only to replace that *one* entity, you can use MySQL's [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```sql
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = REPLACE(my_column, '&#39;', '\'')
```

However, for a more generic answer that will replace *all* HTML entities (whether named or by character code), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14282302).