# How to remove special characters from MySQL Database table column value?

Tags: php, mysql

Scenario is like this ,I have got a field value RIOZ EHG\'\'PAULO inside a column name of a table 'my_cities' in MYSQL Database.My Objective is ,when we select this column field in the query using JOIN ON some 'LIKE' condition ,The record consisting the  name RIOZ EHG\'\'PAULO must be returned, it can be back slash \\ or any other special characters. But Since I use MYSQL 5.6 version,I didn't find a way other than replace function.Below is the query I use. Please guide me .

```
SELECT a.a_town,a.a_country, a.a_code, sc.country_id, sc.name AS city_name,sc.id AS supplier_city_id
        FROM
          my_cities AS sc 
         INNER JOIN
        address AS a
      ON sc.country_id = a.a_country
     AND trim(a.a_town) LIKE CONCAT(trim(sc.name), '%') 
     AND a.a_code = 'address_code' LIMIT 1
```

In this query the sc.name will be having value RIOZ EHG\'\'PAULO .

Comment: Replace unwanted symbol with some legal one, space, for example. Or remove it at all (replace with empty string).

Comment: What is the issue with sc.name having \'\' in it? Is it that you are having trouble using it in another query? Is it messing up an HTML form? If we know the problem, we can advise on how to solve the actual problem.

Comment: when I try to filter a record with the help of this query .I dont get the record .But I have a field name RIOZ EHG\'\'PAULO in the table my_cities . Its becoz of the back slashes \\\'  , So I am trying to find a solution where all special characters are filtered to match the record RIOZ EHG  PAULO . IT cud be ( , ) , *, / , or any other characters inside the value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890363/mysql-substitute-html-special-chars-with-utf-equivalents

Comment: any simple way other than using separate function