# Mass replace Null values in DB2 simple way

Tags: replace, null, db2

We have different tables which have been accidentially filled in various fields with null values which are now causing problems when trying to display them.

I know how I could replace them one column by one, but I would like to know if there is **an easy way** to replace all null values in all columns. I did not come up with any possible solution.

Calculating 30 tables with about 80 columns in average this would take a while creating the SQL(s).

**Any suggestions how to simplify this task?**
We use DB2 V9, in case there is a function for it or similar

Thanks in advance

Xavjer

Comment: A word of warning here - there are a number of situations where a null value (that is, lack of another value) is _correct_ (ie, a `birthday` column where a customer has elected to **not** give this information).  Do you need to worry about anything like this - valid nulls?

Comment: If you replace the current null values, new null values could be created in the future. You should use `ALTER TABLE` to redefine the column(s) so they cannot be null.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: No, we have a 'not null' concept, so we don't have any null fields, we have defined standard values for it.

Comment: @Turophile: I know that, but we have a business concept which makes it complicated to change the tables that way. All newly created ones do have this set but for most already existing this is missing. This should be handled by our services to verify that the values are not null but we hade some incidents which unluckily made that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the catalog tables to get the name from the columns you want to modify (all if you want)

```
select 'update ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || trim(tabname) 
  || ' set ' || trim(colname) || ' = '' '''
  || ' where ' || trim(colname) || ' is NULL;'
from syscat.columns
where tabschema not like 'SYS%'
  and XXX YYYY ;
```

(Not tested, but it should be something like this)

This query will generate a set of lines that you will execute (copy/paste) or you cat put in a file and then

```
db2 -tvf file.sql | db2 +p -tv
```

The last where condition is your own condition to filter the catalog. If you want to filter for more criteria, you can use the syscat.tables view.

Comment: This is close to what I need, but the major problem is the following: We have columns which have low-values, but are not null... like 'Example of an entry ##' where the ## are low-values (Hex x'00'), I want to only replace them by spaces, so it becomes 'Example of an entry   '

Comment: Think found that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605768/search-and-replace-part-of-string-in-database

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the db2 luw tools,  but you should be able to generate at least a create table script from the existing table.   With a little but of find and replace magic you could change the create into an alter table that includes the not null with default clause.

Comment: At least I think that alter table can do that... It's a bit hard to follow the syntax diagrams on a mobile device.