# Search and replace part of string in database - what are the pitfalls?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace, str-replace

I need to replace all occurrences "google.com" that are met in the **SQL** db table Column1 with "newurl". It can be a full cell value, a part of it (substring of varchar()), can be met even several times in a cell.

Based on [SO answer search-and-replace-part-of-string-in-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605768/search-and-replace-part-of-string-in-database)

this is what I need:

```
UPDATE
    MyTable
SET
    Column1 = Replace(Column, 'google.com', 'newurl')
WHERE
    xxx
```

However, in that answer it is mentioned that

`You will want to be extremely careful when doing this! I highly recommend doing a backup first.`

What are the pitfalls of doing this query? Looks like it does the same what any texteditor would do by clicking on Replace All button. I don't think it is possible in my case to check the errors even with reserve copy as I would like to know possible errors in advance.

Any reasons to be careful with this query?
Again, I expect it replaces all occurences of `google.com` with 'newurl' in the Column1 of MyTable table in the SQL db.

Thank you.

Comment: Suppose the string 'google.com' were used in text as not part of a URL. That is one reason why you might be careful. I would recommend using a regular expression replace (I think that is possible in SQL Server) so you know you're only replacing URLs. But yes, a backup is also a very good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a test table, as a replica of your original source table, complete the update on there and check results.

You would want to do this as good SQL programming practice to ensure you don't mess up columns that should not be updated.

Another thing you can do is get a count of the records before hand that fit the criteria using a SELECT statement.

Run your update statement and if it's a 1-1 match on count, you should be good to go.

The only thing i can think of that would happen negatively in this respect is that additional columns get updated. Your WHERE clause is not specific for us to see, so there's no way to validate that what you're doing will do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

I think the person posting the answer is just being cautious - This will modify the value in Column1 for every row in MyTable, so make sure you mean it when you execute.  Another way to be cautious would be to wrap it in a transaction so you could roll it back if you don't like the results.